# "Fix continuation lines" popup

Tags: mu4e

Yesterday I started getting this popup in Emacs:

```
Emacs-x86_64-10_10

Fix continuation lines?
```

[image]

It happens after I write an email in mu4e and send with delay ([Github repo](https://github.com/bandresen/mu4e-send-delay/)). If I click Yes or No, the popup appears again, and then I get a message in the mini-buffer, "Blocking call with quit-process inhibited" (or something like that).

How can I fix it?

Comment: explanation of [continuation lines](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Continuation-Lines.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I had defined a function to insert quick-text:

```
(defun t ()
  (interactive)
  (insert"

Thank you!
")
  )
```

The function name was `t`, the first letter of the quick text, which was probably called when other functions used `t` for `true`. Upon sending an email, Emacs added those lines at the top of the text above the headers, when an email header like recipient and subject has to be on its own line (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757290/http-header-line-break-style)).

Comment: I’m somewhat amazed that emacs lets you define a function called `t`. (Also note that all emacs lisp symbols live in the same namespace so you it’s generally good advice to put something uniqueish (like your name) in all function names or global variables to avoid clashes)